# Nested classes in c#

Tags: c#, class, subclass

Sorry I'm kinda new to c# how would I make a class where I can access it like this: 
Myclass.subclass.method();

This is what I have now:

```
namespace zzcore
{    
    class myclass
    {
        class subclass
        {    
            public static void method() { }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Comment: Note that “subclass” usually means “derived class”, i.g. `class SubClass : BaseClass`. What you're showing is called a “nested class”.

Comment: Note that the recommendation is not to use public nested classes. Consider an extra namespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens here is that a nested class without a visibility modifier is implicitly `private`. In this context, `private` means that only the parent class can see it.

Declare both classes as `public` and you will be able to call `myclass.subclass.method();`

```
namespace zzcore
{    
    public class myclass
    {
        public class subclass
        {    
            public static void method() { }    
        }    
    }    
}
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/tJVKJ